# How can I get only the figure of a symbol in Binance API using Python

Tags: python, get, symbols, binance, ticker

This is my code:

```
import requests
import json
import re
requisicao = requests.get('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=ETHUSDT')
cotacao = json.loads(requisicao.text)
print ('BINANCE BTC = U$',cotacao)
```

OUTPUT

```
{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '2013.44000000'}
```

and that is not what I wanted,

This is what I wanted it to look like: `2013.44000000`, only the digits

Comment: *why* do you expect other people to format your code for you? i think that's kinda unfair tbh.

Comment: @rv.kvetch He tried to format, it's his first question, if you open the edit box you'll notice that he tried to put the ```<>``` for spacing and formatting, it happens.

Comment: I can't open the Edit window at all, that's the problem. I see a pending review for edit which I approved, but the thing I don't like about SO is i can't see the original format of the question when such a situation comes up. But, I guess i'll take your word for it anyway.

Comment: @rv.kvetch I understood what you meant about this problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to define which object you want from the response, for this case we have two options:

```
cotacao['symbol']
```

or

```
cotacao['price']
```

So, for your need we can define it like this:

```
import requests
import json
import re

requisicao = requests.get('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=ETHUSDT')
cotacao = json.loads(requisicao.text)
print (cotacao['price'])
```

Output:

```
2013.44000000
```

Comment: Hi @DeziLuv ```print(float(cotacao['price'])-1000)``` please, if my answer solves your problem, please mark it with the problem solved checkmark to close the question. (tip: never write with CAPSLOCK activated, this is prohibited in the community, I suggest you edit this comment and write the text without CAPSLOCK.)

Answer (score 1):

You should use get method to fetch value from attribute price.
`print(cotacao.get('price'))`